# What is wrong in my IPtables-rules?

Tags: iptables

I'm new to linux, using Ubuntu 16.10 as desktop, but with minecraft server for select amount of IP's. And ssh just for my country. Now I don't even get to adding these specific ip's for the minecraft server.
I try to setup IP tables with standard policies 'DROP', but when I set OUTPUT 'DROP' I can not browse the internet anymore. What should I change?

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Feb 11 15:31:16 2017
*filter
# 1. Delete all existing rules
-F
# 2. Set default chain policies
:INPUT  DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT DROP
# 1. Allow outbound DNS
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp  --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
#2. loopback toestaan
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
#3. reeds geverifieerde connecties toestaan in afgekeurde droppen
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
#4. SSH toestaan, alleen uit Nederland
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m geoip --source-country NL  -j ACCEPT #this country-part works
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#5. http en https outgoing toestaan
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Feb 11 15:31:16 2017
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not browse the internet because you do not have a rule that allows it. You need to allow outgoing traffic to destination ports 80 and 443:

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

By the way, your external SSH connections are not limited to just your own country, because later on, after your country specific rule, you allow it anyhow.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I was not aware of the difference in sport and dport, so I thought I had port 80 outbound covered but no. Yes I saw I still had 22 in the list for multiport. Corrected that too now. Thank you very much, it is working now.

Comment: @GuidovanHaasteren : Then please accept my answer, so that others know this one is solved.